# EventListener won't work in iframe but works outside of it

Tags: javascript, iframe

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

</head>

<body>


      <iframe id = "iframe" src = "https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2656/8500/products/starlight-stars-navy-blue-gold-wallpaper-m1490.jpg?v=1554116082"></iframe>


</body>
```

^HTML

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

//detect print screen windows
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 44) {
    alert("printed");
    

  }
});


$("#iframe").keyup(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode == 44) {
    alert("printed");
    

  }
});

</script>
```

The alert pops up when you press prnt screen but if you click on the iframe and press prntscreen, it doesn't pop up. Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: Scripts in cross-domain iframes **cannot** cross the iframe boundary, for obvious security reasons. Imagine if I loaded your bank's website into an `<iframe>` on my website - if your code worked I could use it to keylog your bank password.

Comment: I tried the same thing with an image in the same folder as the html file, still didn't work @Dai

Comment: An image is not an iframe.

Comment: @Dai, give me one thing I can put in that iframe to make the code work then.

Comment: I can't, because there isn't anything you can do to make the code work. It's all by-design. **Scripts cannot access or interact with cross-origin iframes**.

Comment: please show me an example of a non-cross-origin iframe

Comment: A same-origin iframe would be an `<iframe src="anotherPage.html"></iframe>` or similar: note that `anotherPage.html` must exist **on the same origin** (website domain name, port number and URI scheme/protocol). Scripts can cross same-origin iframe boundaries because it's assumed that pages on the same website domain-name belong to the same person/organization and also because (with a few exceptions I won't get into) they will have the same cookies, so it's deemed there's no substantial security risk. Cross-origin iframes block scripts for reasons like the bank example I gave in my top comment.

Comment: I just changed the src of the iframe to a .html file in the same folder so it's definitely on the same origin. We still have the same event listener problem.

Comment: I suspect the problem there is that you're setting the `keyup` listener before the `<iframe>` is rendered. How are you running that JavaScript? I don't see any `<script>` elements in the HTML you posted. How are you running jQuery?

Comment: <script> elements are obviously there because the window event listener wouldn't work. There's a jquery script code there but I haven't included it on here. Jquery definitely works on this page

Comment: Please post an **accurate minimal reproduction**, including all `<script>` elements. Are any errors or warnings reported in your browser's Dev Tools console?

Comment: edited and no errors in dev tools console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's a **[cross-origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) `<iframe>`** to a page on a website you don't control then there is nothing you can do to listen to DOM events raised inside an `<iframe>` element. This is for security reasons, to paraphrase my upvoted comment from earlier:

> Scripts in a cross-domain `<iframe>` cannot cross the `<iframe>` boundary for obvious security reasons. Imagine if I loaded your bank's website into an `<iframe>` on my website that you opened: I could use `keyup` events raised by your bank's website that are listened-to by my host-page to record your online banking passwords and more.

If it's a **same-origin `<iframe>`** (and a page you control) then the *best way* is to use `postMessage` to allow an iframe to communicate, like so:

---

#### loadedIntoIFrame.html

In your page (which is loaded into an iframe) you need to use `postMessage` to send a message to another frame or iframe.

Note that `postMessage` **can** be used between cross-domain webpages. However it is an *opt-in* system: unlike with same-origin iframes where the host page's scripts have full and direct access to the iframe's document's DOM, `postMessage` requires the other page to *agree* to handle

```
<head>
    <!-- [...] --->

    <script>
if( window.parent ) {
    document.addEventListener( 'keyup', onDocumentKeyUpPostMessageToParent );
}

function onDocumentKeyUpPostMessageToParent( e ) {
    if( e.isComposing || e.keyCode === 229 ) return; // Skip IME events.

    document.getElementById( 'thisPageKeyCode' ).textContent = e.keyCode.toString();

    const msg = {
        keyCode: e.keyCode
    };   

    const targetOrigin = 'http://localhost'; // This MUST exactly match the origin of the <iframe>'s host-page (note that an "Origin" is *NOT* the page's full URI).

    window.parent.postMessage( msg, targetOrigin );
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>this is the iframe content page</p>

    <p>last <code>keyup</code> event in this page: <span id="thisPageKeyCode"></span></p>

</body>
```

#### hostPage.html

In your host page, set-up a listener for `postMessage` events:

```
<head>
    <!-- [...] --->

    <script>
window.addEventListener( 'message', onMessageReceived );

function onMessageReceived( e ) {

    const msg = e.data;  // `e.data` is the same as the `msg` object in the iframe page's script.
    const keyCode = msg.keyCode;

    document.getElementById( 'lastIFrameKeyCode' ).textContent = keyCode.toString();
}
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <p>this is the iframe host page</p>

    <p>last <code>keyup</code> event in iframe: <span id="lastIFrameKeyCode"></span></p>

    <iframe style="border: 3px inset #ccc;" src="loadedIntoIFrame.html"></iframe>
   
</body>
```

---

### JSFiddle example

Here is a JSFiddle example showing iframe communication with `postMessage`:

https://jsfiddle.net/daiplusplus/n0bpedxa/11/

Note:

- The JSFiddle for the **host page** is https://jsfiddle.net/daiplusplus/n0bpedxa/11/
- The JSFiddle for the content of the iframe is here: https://jsfiddle.net/daiplusplus/uzrmj49n/7/
- The the actual origin of these iframes (as of Q3 2020) is `https://fiddle.jshell.net`.

  - This will need to be updated if JSFiddle ever change their `Origin` value.

Screenshot proof:

[image]

Comment: i added the first script to the html file loaded into the iframe and the second script to the page discussed here, still doesn't work

Comment: @aujarmani Did you update the `targetOrigin` value? Are you using a local webserver (e.g. `http://localhost`) or using `file://` ?

Comment: @aujarmani And are any errors or messages reported in your console?

Comment: i tried with file://(long address) and just normal "index.html", neither work

Comment: @aujarmani You really need to use a local webserver for this. Browsers treat `file://` very differently to `http://localhost`.

Comment: Using a webserver made it work. Thanks for all your help.